# Are there ubuntu drivers for Dell DA100 adapter?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, dell

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop for which I purchased a Dell DA100 adapter in order to be able to display on an external monitor through the adaptor's vga port
(http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&l=en&s=dhs&cs=audhs1&sku=492-11742).

I have dual boot Windows7 and ubuntu 14.04. While the external monitor displays fine with Windows7, with ubuntu the external monitor is not detected at all.

I contacted Dell support who said that there is no ubuntu driver for the Dell DA100 adaptor. Can anyone confirm that this is case? If anyone has a suggested workaround, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +audrey any solution?

Comment: Poke...any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Dell DA100 is based on DisplayLink hardware, so you might have some luck by using their reference Ubuntu drivers: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php

Comment: This did not work for me. One of the drivers did manage to display 3 screens, but the HDMI output (not adapter) was ruined by that. In the end i had to remove the driver in order to use my native hdmi port